# Different mark on Dauds hand?

Tags: dishonored

In Knife of Dunwall when using Void Gaze and looking towards a Rune or Bone Charm, what is the symbol on Dauds hand, and why is it different from the Outsiders mark?

Comment: Upvoted because now I'm tempted to reinstall dishonored just to see this.

Comment: Gaming conspiracy. love it. tempted to bounty

Answer (score 3):

The symbol is not different, it is, indeed, his Outsider's mark.
 [image: The outsider's mark]

Here's a screenshot I just took of Daud's mark in the situation you described:
[image: Daud's mark]

If we look closely, we can see this is indeed his Outsider's mark. 
Outsider's mark provided above for comparison.